# How to retrieve data from the selected listview item?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How to retrieve the items from the selected item of a listview ?

[multiselect is set to to false]

I want to get data from the selected Listview Item and put it in a textbox.

I need subitems too

I tried this `Textbox1.Text = List.SelectedItems().ToString` but its not working

Comment: Could you post more information about what you are trying to do?  For instance, what kind of "subitems" are you talking about?  What kind of data are you storing in the listbox.items (just strings?)?  If there is more than one SelectedItem, how do you want it displayed in the textbox?  Is it a multiline textbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
If List.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
    Textbox1.Text = List.SelectedItems(0).Text
End If
```

Comment: List.SelectedItems(0).SubItem(1).Text ' will get you second column text

Comment: I love you!  I've been struggling for an hour with ToString and all kinds of other things - text is SOOOO simple!  Thank you - thank you - thank you

Answer (score -1):

For Each item As ListViewItem In listView1.SelectedItems()
    MsgBox(item.SubItems(4).Text)
Next

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, Would be nice to add some explanation or documentation.